# OpenCV multithreading (Windows/.NET) delays several seconds from video capture

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, opencv

I have a multithreaded openCV program that uses 4 threads to do the following:

Thread 1->calls `cvQueryFrame()` which grabs the frame images from the camera one by one and stores them into a `std::vector` `inputBuffer`

Thread 2->performs thresholding on `inputBuffer[0]`, copies result to another `std::vector` called `filterOutputBuffer`

Thread 3->performs optical flow algorithm / draws flow field for the first two elements in filterOutputBuffer, copies result to another `std::vector` called `ofOutputBuffer`

Thread 4->displays the image using `cvShowImage(ofOutputBuffer[0])`

So essentially I was envisioning each thread performing the task on the first element of the corresponding input vector/buffer and storing the result at the back of the corresponding output vector. Sort of like 3 factory workers doing their part on the assembly line, then throwing the end result into a bucket for the next guy.

I setup mutexes for all of the buffers and the program works, only the output is delayed several seconds from the live camera stream.

I ran a non-multithreaded version of the same program (that used one giant while(true) loop) and it ran in real-time with only the occasional stutter.

Why is my concurrent implementation delayed in performance so much?

Below are the thread functions:

```
    void writeBuffer()
    {
        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Capturing frame from camera!" << endl;
        CvCapture *capture = 0;
        IplImage *frame = 0;
        DWORD waitResult;

        if (!(capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0)))
            cout << "Cannot initialize camera!" << endl;

        //now start grabbing frames and storing into the vector inputBuffer
        while (true)
        {
            //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Waiting for mutex to write to input buffer!..." << endl;
            waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            switch(waitResult) 
            {
                // The thread got ownership of the mutex
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //store the image into frame
                    if(!frame)
                    {
                        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error capturing frame from camera!" << endl;
                    }
                    //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Getting Frame..." << endl;
                    inputBuffer.push_back(*frame);
                break; 
                default:
                    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring mutex..." << endl;
            }
            if(!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) 
            { 
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing mutex..." << endl;
            }
            //else cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Done writing to input buffer, Mutex Released!" << endl;
            //signal hDoneGettingFrame
            PulseEvent(hDoneGettingFrame);
        }
            cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Exiting..." << endl;
    }


    void opticalFlow()
    {
    ...
        DWORD waitResult;

        //start grabbing frames from the vector inputBuffer
        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Waiting to read from input buffer..." << endl;
        while(true)
        {
            waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(fMutex, INFINITE);
            switch(waitResult) 
            {
                // The thread got ownership of the mutex
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                    //grab first two frames from buffer (inputBuffer[0-1]) and process them
                    if(filterOutputBuffer.size() > 1)
                    {   
                        frame1 = filterOutputBuffer[0];
                        frame2 = filterOutputBuffer[1];
                        filterOutputBuffer.erase(filterOutputBuffer.begin());
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if(!ReleaseMutex(fMutex)) 
                            cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing filter mutex..." << endl;
                        //else cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Input Buffer empty!" << endl;
                        continue;
                    }
                break; 
                default:
                    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring input mutex..." << endl;
                    continue;
            }
            if(!ReleaseMutex(fMutex)) 
            { 
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing input mutex..." << endl;
            }
    ...
    //Do optical flow stuff
    ...
    waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(oMutex, INFINITE);
            switch(waitResult)
            {
                // The thread got ownership of the mutex
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": WRITING TO OUTPUT BUFFER..." << endl;
                    ofOutputBuffer.push_back(*frame1_3C);
                break;
                default:
                    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring output mutex..." << endl;
            }
            if(!ReleaseMutex(oMutex)) 
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing output mutex..." << endl;
    }
        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Exiting..." << endl;
    }

    void filterImage()
{
    DWORD waitResult;
...

    //start grabbing frames from the vector inputBuffer
    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Waiting to read from input buffer..." << endl;
    while(true)
    {
        waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        switch(waitResult) 
        {
            // The thread got ownership of the mutex
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                //grab first frame and then release mutex
                if(inputBuffer.size() > 0)
                {   
                    frame = inputBuffer[0];
                    inputBuffer.erase(inputBuffer.begin());
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) 
                        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing input mutex..." << endl;
                    //else cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Input Buffer empty!" << endl;
                    continue;
                }
            break; 
            default:
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring input mutex..." << endl;
                continue;
        }
        if(!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) 
        { 
            cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing input mutex..." << endl;
        }
...
//Tresholding Image Stuff
...
        //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Waiting to write to output buffer..." << endl;
        waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(fMutex, INFINITE);
        switch(waitResult)
        {
            // The thread got ownership of the mutex
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": WRITING TO OUTPUT BUFFER..." << endl;
                filterOutputBuffer.push_back(*out);
            break;
            default:
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring filter mutex..." << endl;
        }
        if(!ReleaseMutex(fMutex)) 
            cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing filter mutex..." << endl;

    }
}

void displayImage()
{
    DWORD waitResult;
    IplImage final;
    int c;
    cvNamedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //start grabbing frames from the vector ouputBuffer
    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Waiting to read from output buffer..." << endl;
    while (true)
    {
            waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(oMutex, INFINITE);
            switch(waitResult) 
            {
                    // The thread got ownership of the mutex
                    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                        if(ofOutputBuffer.size() > 0)
                        {
                            //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Reading output buffer..." << endl;
                            final = ofOutputBuffer[0];
                            ofOutputBuffer.erase(ofOutputBuffer.begin());
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            if(!ReleaseMutex(oMutex)) 
                                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing output mutex..." << endl;
                            //else cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Output Buffer is empty!" << endl;
                            continue;
                        }
                    break;
                    default:
                        cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error acquiring output mutex..." << endl;
                        continue;
            }
            if(!ReleaseMutex(oMutex)) 
                cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing input mutex..." << endl;
            //else cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Done reading output buffer, mutex Released!" << endl;

            //cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Displaying Image..." << endl;
            cvShowImage("Image", &final);
            c = cvWaitKey(1);
    }
    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Exiting..." << endl;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
void main()
{
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    oMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    fMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    hDoneGettingFrame = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    hDoneReadingFrame = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    TName[0]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)writeBuffer, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    TName[1]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)filterImage, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    TName[2]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)opticalFlow, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    TName[3]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)displayImage, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(4, TName, TRUE, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(TName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semaphores did the trick! Instead of using separate mutexes, I just created a semaphore and let all the threads work through that.

Thanks, it's running fast and smooth now!

```
void main()
{
    hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore( 
        NULL,           // default security attributes
        MAX_THREADS,  // available count (when a thread enters, it decreases)
        MAX_THREADS,  // maximum count
        NULL);          // unnamed semaphore

    if (hSemaphore == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }


    TName[0]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)writeBuffer, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    TName[2]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)opticalFlow, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    TName[3]= CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)displayImage, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(4, TName, TRUE, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(TName);
}
```

And in the threads...

```
   //instead of separate Mutexes, just wait for semaphore
    waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, INFINITE);
                switch(waitResult) 
                {

                            ...

                            }
                if(!ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL)) 
                    cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": Error releasing input mutex..." << endl;
```

Comment: Not sure what you've done, here.  Each inter-thread queue need its own semaphore to count the queue items and its own mutex to protect the queue from multiple access.  If there are 5 threads with 4 stages between them, you need 4 queues, 4 semaphores and 4 mutexes.

Comment: i created one semaphore, and all of the threads enter to do their work, and then leave. what exactly is the purpose of the semaphore if I have to use mutexes with it?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreaded application shares the CPU times between threads. Therefore, there exists context switches when another thread wanted to be in run state. Possibly, switching between threads increase the cpu time which results the application become slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use threadPool it will minimize the time consumed from CPU to travel between threads.

Comment: perhaps if I move the thresholding and optical flow into the same thread that will minimize the context switches?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with, if I roll the loop of your first thread function around a bit:

```
if(!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)){} 
PulseEvent(hDoneGettingFrame);
waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
```

To put it another way, your first thread holds onto the queue mutex for almost the entire run of the first thread loop, so preventing the second thread from getting anywhere.  I'm guessing that all the other threads' code is the same?

When pushing data round producer-consumer queues in a pipeline, the idea is that you should keep the queue locked for the minimum time only.  Do your processing on a buffer object, then lock the queue, push on the object reference and then immediately unlock the queue. Then signal a semaphore, (or the like), so that the next thread can process the object when it can.

Don't keep the queue locked!  The mutex should not be there for the other thread to wait on for work - it's to protect the queue from multiple access. You need some other signaling to maintain the queue count and for the threads to wait on for work.  Don't use an event for that, no matter how many other examples you've seen on the net - use a semaphore if you have to roll your own producer-consumer queue.

Better - use a P-C queue class that already works - look at the BlockingCollections classes.